# How to plot the AUCPR curve from h2o model in R?

Tags: r, plot, h2o, roc, auc

I did some kind of data analitycs with the h2o.ai platform in R and I want to receive the AUCPR curve for the model / the prediction.

I already tried to use "PRROC" package, but it sees either not working or to slow for my dataset (1.4 Million instances). For the other available packages I don't really know how i can extract the data from h2o model.

```r
pr <- h2o.predict(V_PUF_AGG1_NPI_ALLEX_BINAR.drf.tt.standard, data.test)
```

gives me a prediction matrix (which i can use for further proceeding?):

```r
  predict        p1           p2
1       1 0.9999427 5.731940e-05
2       1 0.9999606 3.939748e-05
3       1 0.9999744 2.556443e-05
4       1 0.9999659 3.413081e-05
5       1 0.9999606 3.939748e-05
6       1 0.9999545 4.554749e-05

[987141 rows x 3 columns]
```

So I'm searching for a quick solution to plot AUCPR curve.

It's easy to get the ROC curve, but there is no way to get an AUCPR curve directly from h2o:

```r
plot(h2o.performance(V_PUF_AGG1_NPI_ALLEX_BINAR.drf.tt.standard, valid=T), type='roc')
```

Thanks - John

Answer (score 4):

You can plot the PRROC of e.g. the test set in the following way, where `mod`is your H2O model object and `test_hf`is your test set.

```
library(tidyverse)

perf <- h2o.performance(mod,test_hf)

metrics <- as.data.frame(h2o.metric(perf))

metrics %>%
  ggplot(aes(recall,precision)) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme_minimal()
```